# Capturing the output of a video file for frame by frame processing

Tags: iphone, ios, video

I am trying to grab the individual frames from a video file (7 seconds long) and running into huge memory issues.

I am loading up an asset with AVURLAsset then creating an `AVAssetReader` and an accompanying `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` (with pixel format `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`).  Everything seems to work just fine except for the massive memory hit that ends up getting my app shutdown by the OS almost instantly.

As soon as I call `[myAVAssetReader startReading]` memory spikes up 25 megs and it only gets worse from there.

Even if I just call `[myAVAssetReader startReading]` then `[myAVAssetReader cancelReading]` and `[myAVAssetReader release]` the 25 megs is never released.  It only gets worse once I go into a loop gathering frames:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sample = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];

    while( sample != NULL )
    {
         CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( sample );

         // Lock the image buffer
         CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( imageBuffer, 0 );

            // Do stuff with the imageBuffer

         // We unlock the  image buffer
         CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( imageBuffer, 0 );

         // done with the sample
         CFRelease( sample );

         sample = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];
    }
```

Any clues as to how to free the memory that the `AVAssetReader` is using?

Comment: Try putting an autorelease pool inside the loop. I don’t know that CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer or copyNextSampleBuffer are returning autoreleased objects but that’s kind of what it feels like from your description.

Comment: Tried with autorelease pool inside the loop and outside (in the block) with no changes to memory footprint.  copyNextSampleBuffer returns a copied object but CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer returns an autoreleased one.