# Capturing frames from a video file for further processing?

Tags: java, video-processing, jmf

I am a beginner in java, recently i have studied about **JMF (Java Media Framework)** from [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jmf/), I have learned that how to play a video file in java programs using **JMF**, Now what I need to do is, I have to capture frames from given video files and then process it using **some image processing algorithm** and then I have to send these from to that player for displaying. Can anyone please suggest me that how to do that.

I have already read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044825/capturing-the-output-of-a-video-file-for-frame-by-frame-processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not required to use JMF, it is probably worthwhile to consider other options at this point. Unfortunately, Xuggle/Xuggler is apparently on hiatus - but if the state of its last release will work for you, they have a [Frame Capture Demo](https://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java) that should be a good starting point.

If you are sticking with JMF, perhaps [Accessing Individual Decoded Video Frames](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/frameaccess-176882.html) 
will point you in the right direction with its info on using a pass-through codec. Note that you'll need to search for a copy of FrameAccess.java if you want the demo code for this option (the link seems to be broken on that page).